# Request.UserLanguages preferred is always EN

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Using different browsers from a german computer i get always english `en` is preferred language and german `de` as the second. What is the reason for this behaviour?

[image]

Comment: As first step to investigate use Fiddler and check what browser actually sends as "accept-language" header.

Comment: For some reason it sends english as accept-language. I think other users do not have this problem on their workstations. Thanks.

Comment: Developer's machines tend to get into such state - some tools require particular language (often en-US) to be default, some bug require changing languages to repro. Steps by Mahesh Kava would resolve it (till some potentially automated step resets it back :)... )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it depends on what language was selected during the first install of the browser. You should be able to change the language preference order in the browser settings.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Browsers and the preferences are the german language. Can not change anything.